# Is there a way to stop a program after x amount of tries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that asks for user input, and in one of the if statements I was trying to instruct the program to stop after the user had entered an incorrect command x amount of times. I was wondering if there's a function in python that would allow me to do this. I have found a way to stop the program after some time has gone by, but I wish to hault it by amount of times the user inputs a command.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: you want it to halt indefinitely? As in, freeze? Just do a `while(True):`

Comment: But while (true) would continue to run the program until the user inputs a correct command right? I want the program to completely stop after the user enters, lets say, 3 times a wrong command. So if the correct commands are: Blue, Red and Green, if the user types yellow, orange and purple the program then stops.

Comment: you'd put the while(True) afterwards to make your program freeze. If you want it to close, just end the program ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a skeleton code based on what you want to do:

```
incorrect = 0
max_tries = 3
choices = ['red', 'green', 'yellow']

while incorrect < max_tries:
    user_input = raw_input()
    if user_input not in choices:
        incorrect += 1
    else:
        rest_of_the_code(user_input)
        incorrect = 0

if incorrect == max_tries:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Modify it accordingly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was really over thinking this whole thing!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the python script, use:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Note that this will halt all execution of the script. Not sure if that is what you wanted by reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
for _ in range(guesses):
    guess = input(...)
    if guess in correct:
        whatever_next()
        break
else:
    print("Out of guesses.")
```

Comment: your code is invalid. The `else` has no corresponding `if`.

Comment: @RedAlert the `else` corresponds to the `for`, and runs if the loop ends "naturally" (doesn't `break`).

Comment: @RedAlert http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 0):

```
attempts = 0
threshold = 3  # or whatever x you want
while attempts < threshold:
    guess = input(...)
    if is_correct(guess):
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong guess. Retry")
else:
    print("Maximum attempts exceeded")
```